# Can I create directories with dynamic names on run time using Ruby1.9?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have to download files from the web over several requests. The downloaded files for each request have to be put in a folder with the same name as the request number.

For example:

My script is now running to download files for request number 87665. So all the downloaded files are to be put in the destination folder `Current Download\Attachment87665`. So how do I do that?

***Destination folder:***   `Current Download` is fixed. only need to create `Attachmentxxxxxx` dynamically, where `xxxxxx` any request number.

**This is Python version of code:** *but I want it in a Ruby, just for your reference to understand what I am looking for*

```
request_number = 82673

# base dir
_dir = "D:\Current Download"       

# create dynamic name, like "D:\Current Download\Attachment82673"
_dir = os.path.join(_dir, 'Attachment%s' % request_number)

# create 'dynamic' dir, if it does not exist
if not os.path.exists(_dir):
    os.makedirs(_dir)
```

Comment: You do it exactly the same way you would create a directory/file with "static" name.

Comment: Converting your Python code to Ruby is a very simple and straightforward task, which you shouldn't need any help doing. Simply investigate the methods available to you in the [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html) and [`Dir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html) classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can multiple downloads be occurring at once? If so you need something that can randomly create the number with no chance of there being a collision.

Take a look at Ruby's Tempfile module, which is made to do what you're talking about, in particular, the [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#method-c-open) method.

> A utility class for managing temporary files. When you create a Tempfile object, it will create a temporary file with a unique filename.

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.path      # => A unique filename in the OS's temp directory,
            #    e.g.: "/tmp/foo.24722.0"
            #    This filename contains 'foo' in its basename.
file.write("hello world")
file.rewind
file.read      # => "hello world"
file.close
file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
```

Also read the document about "Explicit close" and "Unlink after creation".

No matter what you do, the more files that exist in a given folder, the longer it will take for the system, or your code, to generate a unique filename.

You could use a database to keep track of a serial number also.

And, "[Generate unique filenames](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/64226)" talks about this problem too, with many solutions. The best is probably to use `uuidgen` on *nix systems.

> The uuidgen command generates a Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID), a 128-bit value guaranteed to be unique over both space and time.

Comment: Yes. you are right partially. I have to download `10000 +` files through the script, from 600 requests form. Just to Audit purpose i have to keep them in a separate folder.Thus I need folder creation dynamically and the name of the folder would be `Current Download + requestnumber` as I mentioned in the description. I need to store those files permanently in the local disk for Audit.

Comment: If you read the docs, it lets you specify the folder name on the fly. The files can auto-delete, or not, it's up to you, and is controlled by how you set up your code. See the "Explicit close" section.

Comment: `+1` for the suggestions! interesting one is `You could use a database`. here a bit explanation can i have from you?

Comment: Could you please see mu updated description, hope it will help you to understand what exactly i am looking for!

Comment: Look into database Serial data-types. They're used to generate sequences of numbers over a huge range of values, and, are often used for this sort of problem.

Comment: Can you help me in the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257012/how-to-open-pop-up-window-table-i) ?

Comment: I fixed the tags for that question. It's has nothing to do with Ruby or Selenium, only HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Dir.mkdir("#{Rails.root}/#{whatever}/#{example.join('bla')}")`.
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir

Comment: Could you please see mu updated description, hope it will help you to understand what exactly i am looking for!