# how to open pop up window table using selenium webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3, firewatir

there is `text label` on a webpage, and I am trying to click on that to open a pop-up window,but not getting opened. here is the `HTML` code:

```
<td width="40%">
  <div id="EmpId.outline">
    <input type="hidden" name="EmpId" value="" id="popupEmpId">
    <input type="text" name="EmpCode" value="" readonly="readonly" class="textMedium250" id="popupEmpCode" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;<a href="#f2"><label  onclick="checkForPopup('EmpPopupDiv','Select a Emp',640,true,refreshConditionOptions);">&nbsp;+&nbsp;Search&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;Emp</label> </a>
 </div>
</td>
```

I have to click on the label `+ Search for a Emp`, but could not do that.

Comment: Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Please share the code for your `checkForPopup` function. Also, "but could not do that" doesn't make a lot of sense. What happens? Is there an error? Does the URL change but the popup fails to appear?

Comment: who changed the tag, I was looking for a Ruby solution of the same.Not the html one!

Comment: I am doing web automation using selenium web-driver, but at this point i got stuck. couldn't understand how to code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find element by xpath and click. Based on your example, the xpath to find/click should be something like this:

```
"//a[@href='#f2']"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td width="40%">
  <div id="EmpId.outline">
    <input type="hidden" name="EmpId" value="" id="popupEmpId">
    <input type="text" name="EmpCode" value="" readonly="readonly" class="textMedium250" id="popupEmpCode" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;<a href="#f2" onclick="checkForPopup('EmpPopupDiv','Select a Emp',640,true,refreshConditionOptions);"><label  >&nbsp;+&nbsp;Search&nbsp;for&nbsp;a&nbsp;Emp</label> </a>
 </div>
</td>
```